# Does $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ imply that $u$ is a solution to Laplace's equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ imply that $u$ is a solution to Laplace's equation?

I.e. that $\Delta u = 0$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. All polynomials are in $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$, and most of them don't satisfy Laplace's equation.

Comment: Aha, so one must add that $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ and $u$ satisfies Laplace's equation. In order for it to be a solution to Laplace's equation.

Comment: Saying "$u$ is solution of the Dirichlet's problem" implicitly means that $u$ satisfies the PDE.